# Special characters in ssmtp password

Tags: email, gmail, smtp

I have `+` and `=` characters in my gmail password. How can I configure `ssmtp` to avoid authorization error?

My `/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf`:

```
root=username@gmail.com
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:465
rewriteDomain=gmail.com
AuthUser=username
AuthPass=1234+=5678
FromLineOverride=YES
UseTLS=YES
hostname=skynet
```

How do I run `ssmtp`:

```
$ echo "email content" | mail -s "email subject" otherMail@gmail.com
send-mail: Authorization failed (535 5.7.1
http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257
hz16sm4385885lab.6)
```

Comment: What program does the error occur in? Please give us some context. Brevity is good, but this is little to work on.

Comment: I've attach some more information to the question.

Comment: Did you try single quotes, that should work for you

Comment: The bug is at https://github.com/ajwans/sSMTP/blob/master/ssmtp.c#L913, I remember I submitted a patch back in 2010...nobody cares. I guess it is a feature, rather than a bug!

Answer (score 8):

There are still a number of outstanding bugs dealing with special characters on the `AuthPass` line in the `/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf` file:

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/pkgreport.cgi?repeatmerged=no&src=ssmtp#_0_3_4

These bug reports are specifically for the `ssmtp` page in Debian, but probably apply to others.

- Debian Bug report logs - [#463196](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=463196): ssmtp cannot parse AuthPass with '=' or ':' in it
- Debian Bug report logs - [#768129](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=768129): ssmtp: Same problem here with "#"

According to these report logs, lines containing the characters <kbd>=</kbd>, <kbd>:</kbd>, or <kbd>#</kbd> are either skipped entirely, or processed in a way that removes the part of password on the right-hand side these characters.

In other words, there is currently no way to "escape" these special characters on the `AuthPass` line.

---

*As a side note, there are a number of devices, such as wireless home printers, that require passwords to be entered on a number pad, similar to those used on telephones. Some special characters are available on these devices, but many cannot be selected.*

*For situations like this, you are (unfortunately) forced to adjust your password for the device.*

*A longer password consisting of letters & numbers is preferred to a shorter one with more punctuation characters.*

---

This question has also been asked and answered very well on the following page:

[What characters are illegal in password in ssmtp.conf?](https://serverfault.com/q/826875/184613)

Comment: The maintainers should consider treating the config file entry as Urlencoded like in some other packages.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following workaround:

```
feed the password directly in the command line argument
```

ssmtp -ap "Hash#Password" ...

```
alternatively put the password in an environment variable.
```

ssmtp -ap $PASSWD ...

Hope it helped.

Answer (score -1):

The answer highly depends on the context in which you are entering or submitting the password. In some formats, you can surround your password in `""`'s, in others you would need to escape the offending characters. This [escape character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character), differs between programs, shells, Operating systems, etc. In Windows batch scripts the escape is `^` while in certain Linux or terminal situations, the escape is `\`.

Comment: I tryed to store my password in `1234\+\=5678` form, but got the same error.

Comment: The context is the `ssmtp` package, not SMTP in general.

Answer (score -1):

Try escaping the second equals sign:

```
AuthPass=1234+\=5678
```